# How to export nicely formatted matrix as a table to MS Word?

Tags: matrix, formatting, stata

In Stata it is possible to export nicely formatted regression results to a MS Word document using outreg. I need to do the same for a matrix.  Can anyone help?  There are a few add ins out there such as mat2txt, tabout, and xml_tab, but I cannot get them to do the simple job of exporting a matrix to excel with a title and column and row names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My `mat2txt2` adds labels, titles, etc. to `mat2txt`.

This question is a duplicate ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9975910/496475 )